# Update SharePoint custom list Displayform on existing site collection?

Tags: sharepoint

I have an existing site collection with a bug that I need to fix where a custom document list has been created along with an override file for the displayform:

`<Form Type="DisplayForm" ToolbarTemplate="BLPDocLibDisplayFormToolBar" SetupPath="pages\kmform.aspx" Url="DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewFormDialog" Path="EditDlg.htm">`

Being a novice at SharePoint I have no clue or can find anything useful out there on how I can update the deployed override file Dispform.aspx as it appears that every list has it's own copy of the file.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question. Do you mean that you have created many lists of this custom type and now need to change the display page to the default one instead of custom?

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's right there are lots of lists using this custom type and I need to fix in a bug in the display page and have all the lists pickup the fix.  Thanks

Comment: I never had this requirement before. Are you a developer? Can you write a utility to go over all list instances and make the change? Experienced developer could do that in an hour

Comment: I am a developer so have no problem writing the code it's just as I'm not familiar with the sharepoint object model it will take me a bit longer, thanks for the tip though it points me in the right direction.

Comment: You basically start from the SPSite object that you instantiate using the URL, from there you loop through SPWeb object and its SPList objects, that shouldn't be more than say 20 lines of code